# visual studio 2017 cannot include some file,but the d3d application can debug

Tags: visual-studio, include, direct3d

[image]
This project is merged from GitHub

[image]
this picture can describe the application debug the situation

just like the picture is expressed， program can include some header file，
but there will be a lot of red lines，maybe is not fault，cause I can debug right

can someone explain this situation? any help can be cool

thanks!

Comment: The lines indicate IntelliSense errors. It looks like you are working in a header. Instead of using the old-school ``#ifndef SYMBOL  #define SYMBOL … #endif`` pattern, just remove that and use ``#pragma once``.

Comment: thank you so much , its work for me,  good for u !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "squiggly lines" are IntelliSense errors, not compilation errors.

The root problem was that the old-school "internal guards" are confusing IntelliSense since this is a header:

```
#ifndef DRAW_INIT_H
#define DRAW_INIT_H

...

#endif
```

While [Lakos](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1370617.Large_Scale_C_Software_Design) loves, loves, loves these they are a bit of a hack. Basically every modern C++ compiler supports a more efficient solution: `#pragma once`. Use that instead.